# Getting weird time like output for csv file

Tags: java

I'm not having trouble with the output I get output that looks like this 
01:08.0 02:07.6 03:07.1 04:07.1 05:07.4 06:07.2 07:07.6 08:07.1 09:07.1 10:07.2
which when i click on gives me corresponding time. The output should actually look like this
1:8.035156,2:7.619141,3:7.105469,4:7.072266
The wrong output only happens when I add the "," character at the end of the append statement.

```
public class GeneCsv {
 public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
File file = new File("file.csv");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/Users/home/fileExpression.csv");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
boolean firstLine = true;
String[] temp = null;
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    if(firstLine== true){


        pw.println(in.nextLine());
        firstLine= false;
        continue;
    }
    else{
    String line = in.nextLine();
    temp = line.split(",");
    for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++){
        pw.append(i + ":" + temp[i] + ",");

    }
    pw.append("\n");
    }
    }


pw.flush();
pw.close();
writer.close();
}
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Is it not picking up a new line? Also Apache commons has a csv reader/writer, maybe take a look at using that http://commons.apache.org/csv/

Comment: Please specify the output what you want.

Comment: I want my out to look like this respective to my input 1:5.524,2:243.452,3:524.52 new line                         1:4.321,2:6.66,3:4.5                                    Unforunately the contents are mashed together and are unorderly

Comment: Can you provide your output? A screenshot maybe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand from your question is that, you need to print each comma separated value in a separate line.

For that just print a newline character `"\n"` outside the `for` loop:

```
for(int i =1; i < temp.length ; i++){
   pw.print(i + ":" + temp[i]);    
}
pw.print("\n");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks HashimR this did indeed help tons.

Answer (score 0):

You never print a new line to pw. Outside the for loop do a `pw.print("\n");`.

Answer (score 0):

Along with putting a newline, if you want to retain the comma you need to append it like this `pw.print(i + ":" + temp[i] + ",")`  as split array will not retain the splitter

Comment: putting the new line character outside the loop and adding the "," at the end of my print statement worked. Unforunately I'm getting weird output corresponding with time everytime I add the "," at the end of the print statement. I just updated the code.

Comment: sorry not clear what weird output you getting. I tried with input firstline new line 8.035156,7.619141,7.105469,7.072266 and got output firstline newline 0:8.035156,1:7.619141,2:7.105469,3:7.072266, only issue I can see is if you have problem with extra comma in the end ?

Comment: Also can you confirm, you viewing the output file 'fileexpression.csv' in some text editor or ms excel ?

Comment: This was my original ouput                                        8.035156 7.619141 7.105469 7.072266            This is what I want my output to look like                              1:8.035156 2:7.619141 3:7.105469 4:7.072266          Unforunately this is what I'm getting                                 01:08.0 02:07.6 03:07.1 04:07.1                                       I dont understand how my output even comes remotely close to this.And btw i'm using ms excel.

Comment: The problem is that excel is treating the data as time field in format mm:ss.0, hence you seeing this weird output. It would be displayed correctly in text editor. One quick solution is to add a SPACE before COMMA i.e. pw.print(" " +i + ":" + temp[i] + ",") to see the correct value in excel (but it will have extra white space)

Comment: Thank you coder, i'm going to used a different text editor instead.